# Modifying Quine-McCluskey Algorithm for Different Cost Function

Tags: algorithm, logic, computer-science, cad, computer-science-theory

The standard cost function for [Quine-McCluskey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine%E2%80%93McCluskey_algorithm) seems to involve minimizing the number of AND gates. For my purposes, I need to minimize the number of literals instead of the number of AND gates (for example, I would choose ab+cd over abcde since it has 4 literals instead of 5, even though it has 1 more AND gate). Can anyone give me some pointers on how this different cost function would change the algorithm?

Comment: this question can be asked on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ for better clearance

Comment: Too bad I can't get two Tumbleweed medals.